# cordova file transfer to s3 AWS returns 501 error

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am uploading picture from fileURI to amazon following this very simple method

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
          console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);

          var options = new FileUploadOptions();
          options.chunkedMode = false;
          options.httpMethod = 'PUT';
          options.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'Content-Length' : fileObj.size
          };

          var ft = new FileTransfer();
          constructSignedUrl(picname, 'put').then(function (url) {
            console.log(url)
            ft.upload(fileURI, url,
              function (res) {
                deferred.resolve();
              },
              function (error) {
                deferred.reject();
              },
              options);
          });
        });
      });
```

the constructSignedUrl(picname, 'put') is a method to construct the presigned url.It is working and  I tested it is fine with postman

The server returns this error

```
Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>
```

Seems like  file upload transfer is adding a header and I could not got rid of it, how can I fix this ?

UPDATE : When checking the load on charles proxy I see the header

```
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

Still present, how can i override it. I have already set chunked mode false.

Comment: `'Content-Length' : '0'`?  You're telling S3 you're uploading an empty file?

Comment: I reupdated and restested the function with content-length is file size. but still getting the same error

Comment: Is it necessary to explicitly set Content-Length at all?

Comment: I tried with and without, nothing is working. i have updated the question, the problem is that the plugin always add Transfer-encoding

Comment: @MedTumy Hey did you find a solution to this problem? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Ok I had the same issue with cordova-file-transfer version 1.6.0

Doing down to version 1.5.1 solved my problem.
I Guess this error have something related to do with 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/pull/141

Anyway:

`cordova plugin add cordova-file-transfer@1.5.1` 
worked for me